# identification request - medium size fly invasion

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I have two invasions going on!

the one here: [identification request - tiny flies invasion](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/94217/identification-request-tiny-flies-invasion)

and this one:

[image: small dark fly]

We are in Berlin, Germany. This fly is 2.5mm long vs 1mm wide, and seems to like the dark and colder area of the apartment. They arrived at the same time as the tiny ones in the other link, but they don't look similar, so I don't think this is the adult form of the other kind but maybe I'm wrong.

They came with the heat, looking for shelter.

Comment: Without a clear view of the wing venation any answer would be sheer speculation; if the critters are still around and you can get a photo showing all the wing venation clearly (all we can see for certain at present are the ends of two of the longitudinal -- as opposed to cross -- veins) adding such would help immensely.

Comment: @ArthurJFrost, we're currently in another country; but when we're back I will check if they are still around